# how to delete first occurrence of each group in sas table?

Tags: sql, sas

I have data as follows:

```
ID,date
1,27-08-2020
1,28-08-2020
1,30-08-2020
2,05-08-2020
3,06-08-2020
3,10-08-2020
```

I have to delete first occurrence for each ID group. so that data becomes

```
ID,date
1,28-08-2020
1,30-08-2020
2,05-08-2020
3,10-08-2020
```

How to do that in sas/sql.

Comment: Do you have multiple records per ID and date?  If you have multiple records on the first date for a particular ID value then it will be hard to delete only one of them with SQL.  Most solutions will delete all observations for that date instead.

Comment: No same ID will have unique date(actually timestamp) and I want to delete the first created record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date > (select min(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

You can also incorporate this idea into a `delete`:

```
delete from t
where t.date = (select min(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in a SAS data step using `first.` if the data is sorted correctly.

```
proc sort data=have;
by id date;
run;

data want;
set have;
by id date;
if not first.id;
run;
```

This will remove the first `ID` from each group. Alternatively, you could keep only the first `ID` if you change the statement to `if first.id;`. There is also an equivalent `last.` statement you can use to pull the last record of a group.

Answer (score 0):

You want to retain one row from each group, even when the group has only one row.

Example:

Use `LAST.<byvar>` to deal with cases of one row groups.

```
data have;
attrib ID length=8 date format=ddmmyyd10. informat=ddmmyy10.;
input ID date; datalines;
1 27-08-2020
1 28-08-2020
1 30-08-2020
2 05-08-2020
3 06-08-2020
3 10-08-2020
;

data want;
  set have;
  by ID;
  if first.ID and not last.ID then delete;
run;
```